# How can I exit Windows Explorer in Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer

In Windows 7, I could terminate the `explorer.exe` process by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-right clicking the Start menu and clicking `Exit Explorer`.

How can I do this in Windows 8?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Now, you need to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>-right click the taskbar:

[image]

Comment: Huh, never knew this. Why *would* you need to do this?

Comment: If you needed to do some registry changes related to the explorer. For example if I wanted to enable the watermark when its disabled I would need to restart the explorer.exe as it relates to the Desktop.

Comment: @CalebJares: To unload a shell extension DLL.

Comment: Ah, interesting.

Comment: To restart the Explorer. 1. Press Ctrl+Alt+Del 2. Select Task Manager 3. File -> Run New Task 4. Type explorer and click ok. Thought it might be worth mentioning, no explorer can be scary the first time :D

Comment: I remember in 2000/XP one had to press Control+Shift+Alt and click on Cancel in the "Turn off computer" dialog. BTW, while the above method (via the menu) is cleaner, it will only close the Explorer process that managed the Desktop, so if you've enabled "Launch folder windows in a separate process" you still have to manually close the other Explorer process via Task Manager.

Comment: @Karan The 2000/XP method still works in Vista and 7.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Where's the "Turn off computer" dialog?

Comment: @Karan Open Start Menu -> double AltF4.

Comment: @kinokijuf: Duh! I've seen it before when keeping Alt+F4 pressed to close multiple apps, since when no apps are open pressing it shows that dialog (even with apps open you can click the Desktop and press Alt+F4 to show it). Of course, I've almost forgotten how it looks since I use the Power Options menu in the Start Menu. Thanks for the update; never occurred to me to try it in Win7! (Hopefully it works in Win8 as well.)

Comment: Using the same method, in Windows 8, the desktop is closed, but `explorer.exe` is still alive.
In Windows 7, `explorer.exe` is closed completely.

Answer (score 1):

Thought I'd give an alternative as well:

1. <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>
2. `taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`

To restart explorer:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd> to start Task Manager
2. File, Run new task
3. Type `explorer` and hit enter

Comment: This would not be a clean exit though. Killing the process from the command line or Task Manager may result in changed settings not being being saved etc. The only clean way I know of is the one SLaks mentioned.

Comment: Would it be if you removed the `/F`?

Comment: I think it would still not allow a proper close even without the /F.

Comment: What is the advantage of a clean close? I've never used Slaks' method before.

Comment: @CalebJares: Removing `/F` will not help.  Cleanly exiting will allow explorer to unload things that it's using; I don't know specific benefits.

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned, allows it to unload properly (including any shell extensions etc.), save changed settings and so on. Don't know the exact internals though, just what I have read about the menu method being the safe option.