# Close all Modern UI apps at once

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-app

Is there a shortcut to close all Modern UI apps at once from the Desktop?

I tried killing `RuntimeBroker.exe` but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to **PC Settings** (open Charms bar, click on *Settings* and then click on *Change PC Settings*) and click on **General**, you’ll see an option under App Switching called **Delete History**.

Clicking it will clear all app history, including killing the running apps.

More info [here](http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-close-running-metro-apps-clear-app-history-in-windows-8/) and [here](http://www.online-tech-tips.com/featured-posts/5-ways-to-speed-up-windows-8/).

Comment: Yes, you are right but I want to do it from the desktop.

Answer (score 2):

On Windows 8; all "modern" applications seem to be dependent on explorer.exe. Restarting the process from Task Manager seems to stop all Windows 8 (modern) applications.

Comment: http://superuser.com/q/495686/1503